# MySQL Array in Listbox

Tags: c#, mysql, listbox

I'm totally new to this (trying to understand it since 2 days) but im trying my best :D

I am trying to fill a listbox with a array. I didn't find anything on the internet.

My array has this structure:

```
"[[`license_cop_cAir`,1],[`license_cop_cg`,1],[`license_cop_ausbilder_cop`,1],[`license_cop_MP`,1]]"
```

I want to retrieve it it from my mysql database and fill a listbox and create a row foreach license.

I tried it with this code for testing:

```
string[] test = { "[[`license_cop_cAir`,1],[`license_cop_cg`,1],[`license_cop_ausbilder_cop`,1],[`license_cop_MP`,1]]" };

string[] array = test.ToArray();
```

I hope someone can help me :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use string split function with ],[ this split and after this remove unwanted string like {[' or you can use this

```
string data="[[`license_cop_cAir`,1],[`license_cop_cg`,1],[`license_cop_ausbilder_cop`,1],[`license_cop_MP`,1]]";

data.Split(new string[] { "],[" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

after above code you can use foreach lope for removing [[` this special character.

May be it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Thanks for the help :D

It helped me a little bit but i have another question. I have now a checkedlistbox and i want to make a change and then save the checkedlistbox as array.

my code is now this: http://pastebin.com/sNSZQ8iF

but how can i convert it back to a array ?

greeting basti